# How to remove suffixes from a set of addresses

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a data set containing a list of street addresses. Some of these addresses end in a suffix like "AVE" or "ROAD". I want to remove any of these suffixes that appear in the list of addresses. My approach is to use a Do loop to step through a list.

```
%macro suffixes(field=,newfield=);
%let suffix = AV AVE AVENUE BEACH BLUFF BLVD BOULEVARD;

%let nwords=%sysfunc(countw(&suffix));

%do i=1 %to &nwords;
%let suff=%scan(&suffix,&i);
%let sufflen=%length(&suff);
%if %substr(&field,%length(&field)-&sufflen)=&suff
    %then &newfield=%substr(&field,1,%length(&field)-&sufflen+1);

%end;
%mend;

data addresses_no_suffix;
set addresses_full;

%suffixes(field=addresses,newfield=new_addr);

run;
```

I'm kind of stuck, as the above approach doesn't work, even though all the individual "pieces" seem to work on their own (the "if/then" logic works in the datastep outside of the macro, for instance). Any ideas about how to make this work better or help me understand where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

An example input dataset might look like this:

[image]

And the expected output for the above would look like this:

[image: new_addr 123 Brookfield 234 Wonderland 456 Pickup Stix]

Edited to correct the macro code I've been trying.

Answer (score 2):

Your macro is not generating any lines of SAS code to add to your data step.

You need to replace this macro logic

```
%if %substr(&field,%length(&field)-&sufflen)=&suff %then &newfield='test';
```

With some actual SAS code.  Probably something like:

```
if substrn(&field,length(&field)-&sufflen)="&suff" then &newfield='test';
```

You can turn on the MPRINT option to see in your SAS log the lines of SAS code that your macro generates.

Answer (score 1):

Not use macro loop:

```
%let suffix =AV AVE AVENUE BEACH BLUFF BLVD BOULEVARD;

data want;
  set have;
  word=scan(address,-1);
  if findw("&suffix",word,' ','RI')>0 then New_address=tranwrd(address,strip(word),'');
  else New_address=address;
  drop word;
run;
```